# How to sign out from my web application using okta?

Tags: python, session, flask, session-cookies, okta

Hi everyone Im using okta in order to create a login, my libraries area OpenIDConnect and UsersClient, Im following this tutorial https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/12/flask-tutorial-simple-user-registration-and-login. The login is working and I can even show the name from the current users in the view, but when I go to logout route, the web application redirects but Im still logged in and I can see the name from my users, do you know how to log out and clear the session completely?

```
from flask import Flask,redirect, url_for,g
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_migrate import Migrate,MigrateCommand 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_script import Manager 
from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect
# local imports
from config import app_config
from okta import UsersClient
import requests
db = SQLAlchemy()

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

app.config.from_object(app_config["development"])
#Obtiene la clave secreta y la cadena de conexion del archivo config.py que se encuenstra en la carpeta instance
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "example"
app.config["OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS"] = "client_secrets.json"
app.config["OIDC_COOKIE_SECURE"] = False
app.config["OIDC_CALLBACK_ROUTE"] = "/oidc/callback"
app.config["OIDC_SCOPES"] = ["openid", "email", "profile"]

app.config["OIDC_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME"] = "oidc_token"
oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)
okta_client = UsersClient("example", "example")





#Agrega bootstrap a la aplicacion, en este proyecto solo se utiliza wtf de esta libreria, lo demas son archivos
Bootstrap(app)
db.init_app(app)

""" 
Comandos disponibles para migraciones: python manage.py  db init, python manage.py  db migrate 
, python manage.py  db migrate 
""" 
migrate = Migrate(app, db) 


from Project import models

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if oidc.user_loggedin:
        g.user = okta_client.get_user(oidc.user_getfield("sub"))
    else:
        g.user = None



@app.route("/login")
@oidc.require_login
def login():
    return redirect(url_for("pagina.home"))

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
```

## this logout function is not destroying my session

```
    oidc.logout()


    return  redirect(url_for('pagina.home'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that browser still caches your session data.

you can  set **Cache-control headers** to no-cache conditionally for logged out users as per code below to force the browser to obtain new copy of the page even when they hit "back".

you can achieve that via html pages or directly on your python flask

**From Html page**

For the Web Pages (HTML) add the following  tags to the page(s) you want to keep browsers from caching (the code must be in the  section of your page, for example right after  tag):

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

**from flask end**

```
response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
response.headers["Expires"] = "0"
```

so your code should look like

```
def logout(response):
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers['Expires'] = '0'
    return  redirect(url_for('pagina.home'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your code is not working, after hours I found the answer here https://devforum.okta.com/t/logging-out-of-an-okta-authenticated-flask-app/4616